# How to make iPhone app that fills in memory quickly

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I often try to fix bugs that occur when I use my iphone for other memory hungry stuff and it needs to free some memory and thus unload some views from my app. I found this quite hard to simulate when I need it so I decided to make that will try to allocate as much memory as possible and force my tested app to release unused views etc.

I tried something simple as calling this every few hundred milliseconds but it for some reason didn't do anything

```
[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:malloc(2048 * 1024) length:2048 * 1024];
```

Instruments show that apps is getting bigger and bigger, far beyond memory capacity of iphone (hundreds of mbs allocated) but I don't even get memory warning and it doesn't affect other apps at all. Is there some safeguard that somehow prevents iphone app form doing something like this? Or is there some mistake in my assumptions about how iphone works?
How do you solve this problem when you face it?

EDIT: I am running my app on device, I wasn't able to get my views unloaded on simulator even if I simulated memory warning (this sometimes work, but only rarely)

EDIT2: as bbum pointed out problem was indeed in virtual allocation, simple memset after allocation did the trick

```
void *data = malloc(1024 * 1024);
memset(data, 0, 1024 * 1024);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, what is happening is a tricksy bit of virtual addressing behind your back.

Namely, an application is free to reserve up to the full 4GB of 32-bit address space available to it (less than 4GB, really, because there is fragmentation caused by various system pieces).

When you do `malloc(REALLYBIGNUMBER)`, the system uses `vm_allocate()` to fulfill the request.   The mach memory manager hands you back the addresses, but doesn't actually back it with real memory (kinda like the US economy has tons of $$$ in the market not backed by any real asset).

Physical memory will only be used when you write (or, technically, read) something to the memory.  And it will only happen page by page.

So, if you were to walk through the allocated buffer in strides of 4096 (page size) and write one byte, you'd quickly see real memory being consumed.

Comment: You are right! I suspected similar trickery, but I had no idea that simple read/write would solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Can you not just simulate a memory warning in the simulator using the 'Device' menu?

Comment: I tried that, but even if I try simulate memory warning my views are not unloaded so it doesn't help much

Comment: Turns out I wasn't using simulator properly (didn't know it is even possible :) ) and now it does what it should, so thanks for for pointing me in right direction. But I still would like to know answer to my question so I can test it on device as well

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do to simulate the use of a large block of memory.

```
#define MEGA (1024 * 1024)
- (void)stressTestTheApplicationBySimulatingMemoryScarcity {

    NSUInteger sizeInMB = 20;       // Size in MB. The higher, the more memory will be used here, leaving less for the application
    // On iPad: 30 seems to be the upper limit you can ask. YMMV

#if MEMORY_STRESS_TEST_SCARCITY_ENABLED
#warning MEMORY_STRESS_TEST_SCARCITY_ENABLED - THIS SHOULD NOT HAPPEN IN PRODUCTION
#else
    return;
#endif

    NSLog(@"MEMORY STRESS TEST ENABLED (%dMB)", sizeInMB);

    void * unusedMemoryBufferToSimulateMemoryScarcity = NSZoneCalloc(NSDefaultMallocZone(), sizeInMB * MEGA, 1);

    if (NULL == unusedMemoryBufferToSimulateMemoryScarcity) {
        NSLog(@"MEMORY STRESS TEST FAILED: Was unable to allocate requested memory");
        return;
    }

    dataToRetainToSimulateMemoryScarcity = [[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:unusedMemoryBufferToSimulateMemoryScarcity
                                                                 length:sizeInMB * MEGA
                                                           freeWhenDone:YES] retain];
    if (dataToRetainToSimulateMemoryScarcity == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to retain data to simulate memory scarcity");
    }

}
```

Done this way, the memory allocation is seen by Instruments.
The `memset` solution suggested by bbum might have done the trick instead of the `dataWithBytesNoCopy: length: freeWhenDone:`

The warning and logs left in place help to make sure I do not ship it by error.
If you add some of this code to a project, I suggest you keep them as well (and turn on the *Treat warning as error* option)..

Comment: That looks interesting, how do you call it in your app? do you have some debug button or something?

Comment: I call it in applicationDidFinishLaunching: If the macro MEMORY_STRESS_TEST_SCARCITY_ENABLED is set to 1, it will use and hold the memory. Otherwise, it will be a no-op. But you could call it from wherever you want in your app, even multiple times. You also could replace the macro with a preferences, that would be configurable in a Debug window.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bzero (or otherwise write to every page in) the memory blocks after you allocate them so that the virtual memory system creates all the pages in the block and marks them resident + dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running instruments on a process running on your device or the simulator?
I think in simulator it uses your Mac's memory which is obviously bigger than an iPhone's. Try running it on the device and see what happens?

Disco

Comment: I am running on device (iphone 4), but it can still allocate hundreds of megs of memory without anything happenning